# Delete parenthesis in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to delete words inside parenthesis, as well as the parenthesises (from multiple values in Column Col1) in SQL Server.
I have looked through other posts about this, not succeeding.

What I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    left(Col1, charindex('(', Col1) - 1)
FROM 
    Table;
```

as well as

```
declare @str varchar(100)
set @str='Col1'
select left(@str, charindex('(', @str)-1)
from Table
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You can't. SQL, the language, is bad at text manipulation and what you ask requires a regular expression. T-SQL doesn't have regular expressions.  Why do that with SQL at all?

Comment: Could there be multiple sets of parenthesis? For example, could `'This is(n't) my (in)correct value'` be in your data? Ideally, this isn't something for T-SQL, its pattern matching is poor and it has no built in support for Regex. If you *must* use T-SQL, I would suggest looking for some CLR Regex functions to do Regex replacement.

Comment: I assumed Charindex will do? From this: ”Name 1 (Able I)” 
I want: ”Name 1”.

Some values got parenthesis, some not. Only 1 set of parenthesises in each value

Comment: Well, for the **one** example we have in your question, @l14045 , the value (`'Col1'`) has **no** parenthesis, so the SQL is going to error; `-1` is an invalid value for the second parameter for `LEFT`.

Comment: Oh, that's because Col1 is the name of the Column. The values inside Column 'Col1', is what I want to manipulate.

Comment: Variables can't be used to replace a literal @l14045 . `SELECT @str` means return the value within the variable (`Col1`) ***not*** return the value from the column with the name that has the value of `@str`. SQL is not a scripting language.

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server has lousy string manipulation functionality.  If you want everything up to the first `(` and then after the first `)`, you can use:

```
select (case when col like '%(%)%'
             then concat(left(col, charindex('(', col) - 1),
                         stuff(col, 1, charindex(')', col), '')
                        )
             else col
        end)
```

You can update the table using the same logic:

```
update t
     set col = concat(left(col, charindex('(', col) - 1),
                       stuff(col, 1, charindex(')', col), '')
                      )
     where col like '%(%)%';
```